# Tool for managing CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I've found Kanapes IDE. Which looks like it *could* be useful but the developers have actually produced *zero* documentation. They simply ask that you to follow them on Facebook and Twitter. How is this documentation?! Do you know of any actual (hidden) user docs existing for this app? Or better yet, do you know if anyone has built a better (with actual help) CouchDB management tool? Yes I'm aware of Futon and it's very, very basic. I'm hoping something more/better than Futon exists.

Thanks for your replies :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica). It has rather documentation. Good luck!